# Overnight Layover at LHR for 17 Hours at Terminal 2

Tags: indian-citizens

I am travelling from Delhi to Toronto via LHR. There is an overnight layover of 17 hours at Terminal 2 (Arrival 18:55 and Departure 12:00 on the following day). I am an Indian Passport Holder with Canadian Permanent Resident Card. Do I need to get a transit visa for the overnight layover considering new rule changes recently?

Comment: Which new rule changes? The last major changes I heard about were in 2014, and [the official check-if-you-need-a-visa page](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes) still describes that transit-without-visa should be available for you if your Canadian PR card is issued (or renewed) after 2002.